# Acids that donate just one proton

Tags: acid-base, nomenclature

- What is the general name for acids that can only lose one hydrogen ion? (i.e. $\ce{HCl}$)
- What is the general name for acids that can lose $n$ hydrogen ions? (i.e. $\ce{H_3PO_4}$, which can lose 3)

The answers to these questions are probably mentioned a million times on the internet, but I could not find them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An acid that can donate one hydrogen ion is called monoprotic (i.e., $\ce{HCl}$). An acid that can donate two is called diprotic (i.e., $\ce{H_2SO_4}$). An acid that can donate 3 is called triprotic ($\ce{H_3PO_4}$). I don't know of any which can donate four.

Comment: An acid that can donate $n$ protons is called *polyprotic*, assuming $n > 1$.

Comment: @EricBrown And assuming $n \in \mathbb{N}$. ;-)

Comment: @timjver tough crowd!  :-)

Comment: Just a side note: most polyprotic acids with more than three acidic hydrogens are organic, I believe, the first example that comes to mind being EDTA. There's only one inorganic tetraprotic acid I can think of off the top of my head, and that's pyrophosphoric acid.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot about organic acids! If you make the chain long and branched enough you can squeeze just about as many carboxylic acids in as you want.